# How to set nameserver for the gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following configuration in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: docker:20.10.16
# When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
# improved performance.
variables: 
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  
services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind

pages:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apk add --update openssh )' 
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan $REPO_IPADDRESS >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - docker info
  script:
    - docker --version
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yaml up -d
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - main
```

How can I set nameserver for my gitlab-runner or make it use the nameserver of the OS that it is running on?

Comment: Can you share why you think there is a DNS issue? Where in your job does the DNS error occur? When trying to clone the repo? When trying to use `ssh-keyscan` or is it something happening in your docker-compose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use the nameserver of the OS that it is running on

That should be the [default behavior](https://docs.docker.com/network/#dns-services) and, in my experience, also works with GitLab's docker-in-docker without any additional configuration -- lookups get forwarded to the host's DNS servers. Per the docker docs:

> By default, containers inherit the DNS settings of the host, as defined in the `/etc/resolv.conf` configuration file. Containers that attach to the default `bridge` network receive a copy of this file. Containers that attach to a custom network use Docker’s embedded DNS server. The embedded DNS server forwards external DNS lookups to the DNS servers configured on the host.

But in any case, you can explicitly configure DNS for containers that the GitLab docker runner manages with the `dns` and `search_dns` options in the [`[runners.docker]` section configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section).